# build.gradle no where to found after successful export in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

Hi guys I'm new in android development and I found it strange why I can't find the build.gradle in my project after successfully exported the project. This is what I did.

1. Update SDK to revision 22.0.5.
2. Update my Eclipse Plugin to adjust in 22.0.5 build.
3. Open my eclipse then Export.
4. Select Generate Gradle build files.
5. Click next, then next
6. Then it tells me that successfully exported and give the location of the build.gradle but going to the said directory the file is no where to found.
   [image]

Comment: The same thing happened for be because the build tools were not installed properly. Installing them fixed the problem.